# Star Wars Rebels Season 2 Continuing?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

Does anyone know if and when Season 2 of rebels will air?  I love this series and want to see more but everywhere I look online, I don't see a future airings or future episode list...I'm assuming that they are continuing some time in late winter and finishing around april/may, but again, I can't find any confimation of this on line.

EDIT:  I thought that the title was clear in that i was wondering if and when Season 2 was continuing.  I have thus far seen every episode of season 2, but i feel confident that the season is not over.  However, I can't seem to see when the series will continue.  So that is my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## *Star Wars Rebels* Season 2 will continue with new episodes in January 2016.

According to the [official Star Wars web site](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/star-wars-rebels), Season 2 of *Rebels* began airing on **14 October 2015 on Disney XD.**  You can find Disney XD's schedule [here](http://www.disneyxd.ca/schedule).

It seems that Season 2 will pick up from where it left off some time in January 2016.  The 11th episode, "Legacy", aired in December.  The 12th episode will air in January, according to this preview:

Comment: Maybe they don't get the latest TV releases in New Jersey.

Comment: I should edit my question.  I have watched all episodes thus far.  But there hasn't been a new episode in a couple of weeks.  I was wondering if it will pick up agin.

Comment: @Iceman : What was the last episode that you watched?

Comment: Legacy...about Ezra's parents.

Comment: @Iceman : Thanks.  See update to answer.

Comment: @Iceman Mid-season breaks are very common with TV shows, and often coincide with the holiday break when viewership is down to do special programming and holiday commitments/vacations. I'm sure they probably advertise it on Disney. It's pretty typical for them to do "Show will return in January" kind of adverts.

Comment: Awesome guys...thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The next episode, "A Princess on Lothal," will air on January 20, 2016.

Reference: http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/117/star-wars-rebels/episodes